# Chunk a large dataset by using a string in the column name using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a dataset containing 3000 columns
every column looks like 'abc_dummy0', 'dfg_dummy0, asd_dummy0' and it's of length 130 before it moves onto 'dfg_dummy1'.... and so on until 'lkj_dummy39'

I can use

```
cols = [col for col in df.columns if 'dummy1' in col]
```

And it lists all the columns (130) containing the dummy1 at the end of each column name.

My question is, how can i create smaller chunks of data, each one containing 'dummy0', 'dummy1', 'dummy2'.. and so on all the way till 'dummy39' without doing this 40 times
I think it has something to do with

```
dummy{i} for i in range(0,39)
```

But I am not quite sure how to approach this, in a memory efficient and code efficient way
(because I would just write 40 lines of code for each respective 'dummy' group)

Here's what I can do, one at the time:

```
group_0 = [col for col in df.columns if 'dummy0' in col]
group_0 = df[group_0]
```

but how do I do this for all other 39 groups (both the "_i" at the end of the name and the dummy{i} part) ?

Comment: Its a little unclear what you're looking for. You could split columns on the `_` and group based on that? You could use use `filter` on the dataframe to select values based on a format string, but again, it's unclear how you'd like to use the results.

Comment: It's a research paper so not sure if I am allowed to provide the actual data. but basically, I would like to create 40 new subsets from that massive datafile, each subset being named and containing all the respective 130 columns. For example:
group_0 = all the 130 columns containing 'dummy0'
group_1 = all the 130 columns containing 'dummy1'
and so on until group_39 = all the 130 columns containing 'dummy39'
But how do I also code the naming of the group_{i} subsets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) on axis=1 and create a `dict` entry for each group:

```
dfs = {group_name: frame
       for group_name, frame in
       df.groupby(df.columns.str.split('_').str[-1], axis=1)}
```

`dfs`:

```
{'dummy0':    a_dummy0  b_dummy0  c_dummy0
0        79        62        17
1        28        31        81,
 'dummy1':    d_dummy1  e_dummy1  f_dummy1
0        74         9        63
1         8        77        16}
```

---

Sample Data:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(5)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1, 100, (2, 6)),
                  columns=[f'{chr(3 * i + j + 97)}_dummy{i}'
                           for i in range(2)
                           for j in range(3)])
```

`df`:

```
   a_dummy0  b_dummy0  c_dummy0  d_dummy1  e_dummy1  f_dummy1
0        79        62        17        74         9        63
1        28        31        81         8        77        16
```

groups based on values after the `_`:

```
df.columns.str.split('_').str[-1]
```

```
Index(['dummy0', 'dummy0', 'dummy0', 'dummy1', 'dummy1', 'dummy1'], dtype='object')
```

`dfs`:

```
{'dummy0':    a_dummy0  b_dummy0  c_dummy0
0        79        62        17
1        28        31        81,
 'dummy1':    d_dummy1  e_dummy1  f_dummy1
0        74         9        63
1         8        77        16}
```

Then each group can be accessed like:

```
dfs['dummy0']
```

```
   a_dummy0  b_dummy0  c_dummy0
0        79        62        17
1        28        31        81
```

---

Alternatively with a loop + [`filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html#pandas-dataframe-filter):

```
for i in range(0, 2):
    print(f'dummy{i}')
    curr_df = df.filter(like=f'_dummy{i}')
    # Do something with curr_df
    print(curr_df)
```

Output:

```
dummy0
   a_dummy0  b_dummy0  c_dummy0
0        79        62        17
1        28        31        81
dummy1
   d_dummy1  e_dummy1  f_dummy1
0        74         9        63
1         8        77        16
```

Comment: Every column has 8000 rows, would making a dictionary out of this be a good idea?

Comment: Again. It depends what you want to do with the data... You could of course loop and filter over each group, but then you would be able to "code the naming of the group_{i} subsets". This is one of the only ways you could have _named_ subsets in that way.

Comment: Your sample code makes sense to me, however every column name has two underscores 
name_word_dummy0
should I add the whole '_dummy' to the split part?

Comment: No need `str[-1]` will take the _last_ value regardless of how many splits there are. I've also added the filter option as well.

Comment: Gonna give it a shot and update you. Thank you for the help!

Comment: When using the loop, it works wonder, but how do i access each group?
my_df['dummy0'] 
gives me a 
Key error: 'dummy0'

Comment: Again, when using the loop you only have access to the data inside the loop. In the above example the filtered dataframe is called `curr_df`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this like:

```
[col for col in df.columns for i in range(39) if str(i) in col if 'dummy' in col]
```